# Perfect determination and knowability in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-interpretations

In classical mechanics, it is postulated that in principle the position and velocity of particles are perfectly determined and can be perfectly known. And it is by using such determined properties that the evolution of classical systems can be predicted and computed (at least in principle).

In quantum mechanics, on the contrary, positions and velocities are not perfectly determined together. More precisely, the description of the states of systems are based on wave functions, and indeterminacy such as the one between velocities and positions are embedded in the expressions of the wave functions.

But then, does quantum mechanics postulate that wave functions themselves are perfectly determined, and if so, can they be (at least in principle) perfectly known/knowable? Or are there on the contrary fundamental limits imposed by the theory on what can be known/knowable about a wave function?

More generally, what elements of the theory are postulated to be perfectly determined and perfectly knowable in quantum mechanics? Or is it still a blurred area left to interpretations?

**Edit**

I don't mean 'determined' in the sense of a 'deterministic evolution' (a probability density can evolve deterministically, yet the value of what it describes stays uncertain/undetermined/indefinite...)

I mean 'determined' as in opposed to 'uncertain' from the 'uncertainty principle' (so 'determined' in the sense 'certain' or 'definite'—not referring to the knowledge about something but whether the thing itself has a definite value in the first place). Velocities and positions of quantum objects are fundamentally undetermined (or  uncertain or indefinite) in the theory. What about the wave functions of quantum objects, are they assumed to be fundamentally determined/certain/definite by the theory?

PS: I can see how it is an area where it is hard to find the good terms... Maybe I should have used the terms such as 'definite' and 'definiteness' instead of 'determined' and 'determination'...

Comment: You can know the wave function given a large enough ensemble of identically prepared quantum objects. But for a single quantum object you cannot.

Comment: There are some cases where you can know it exactly. Take a spin state. If you measure the spin projection in the z-axis, then you know its state after measurement exactly.

Comment: "But then, does quantum mechanics postulate that wave functions themselves are perfectly determined..." The wavefunction evolves deterministically according to the Schrodinger equation.

Comment: The wavefunction of a quantum system is fundamentally unknowable, a fact that will become clear if you check the units of the wavefunction: How would you ever measure something that is the square root of cubic metres? What experimental instrument can you use to measure that? We deduce a lot of things with it, but it is not fundamentally knowable.

Answer (score 2):

To the question: "does quantum mechanics postulate that wave functions  themselves are perfectly determined?"

The wavefunction is deterministic. It evolves in a way that can be completely determined. IF you know what that origional wavefunction was.

> can they [the wavefunction] be (at least in principle) perfectly known/knowable

The wavefunction, while itself evolves in a totally determined way, can only be "prefectly known" to you in the same way that the fairness of a coin can be "perfectly known" by flipping it thousands of times. That is, you can make a pretty good guess and you'd have to be very unlucky to be wrong. (And, as the OP points out, you have to repeat the experiment with the assumption that the repeated experiments are identical situations.)

> More generally, what elements of the theory are postulated to be
> perfectly determined and perfectly knowable in quantum mechanics?

The evolution of the wavefunction is completely deterministic. So how that wavefunction evolved at the beginning of time is perfectly determined. It is, however, not knowable to you as the wavefunction collapses and you lose information about what that origional state was when you collapse it.

EDIT:
To address some of the OP's comments. I also want to mention that a quantum MZI can show that a wavefunction can interfere constructively or destructively on a single quantum event. If there was any sort of "uncertainty" in the wavefunction itself, then it wouldn't interfere completely at the other beamsplitter. This experiment shows the effect of deterministic wavefunction interference without requiring a statistical reconstruction of any states.

Comment: Sorry, I was not asking if the evolution is deterministic, I am wondering if the wave function is determined in the sense 'certain' as in opposed to 'uncertain' from the 'uncertainty principle'. Velocities and positions of quantum objects are fundamentally undetermined (uncertain) in the theory. What about the wave function of quantum objects, are they assumed to be fundamentally determined/certain by the theory? A probability density can evolve deterministically, yet the value of what it describes stays undetermined... Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: @TheQuark, you understand why quantum objects are fundamentally undetermined, right? It sounds like to me that you think this is unrelated to the wavefunction itself. When you make a measurement in X, the reason why there is uncertainty in P is because the wavefunction in P itself changes upon measurement in X. Fundamental measurement uncertainty comes /from/ the wavefunction. Is this part clear?

Comment: Yes, I understand that. In fact my question boils down to what are the fundamental, definite 'objects' or properties of objects on which QM rests. Positions and velocities are fundamental definite properties of the objects in classical mechanics, but they do not have this status in QM. At first, I would be tempted to say that the wave function has this status. However, since measurements collapse the wave function, the wave function of a particular quantum object cannot be known, only an 'average' wave function of a population of similar objects can be. (...)

Comment: (...) Which is then identified to the wave function of each object of the population by assuming they all share the same wave function. But this seems a strong assumption, and without this assumption, it seems impossible to get to know/determine any wave function. So this makes me wonder how valid it is to assume/postulate that the wave functions are those fundamental definite object on which QM can rest. Thus my question: are wave functions indeed postulated to be the definite, fundamental (unknowable) objects of the theory, or are there other objects considered more definite and knowable?

Comment: @TheQuark, as said in my answer, this "strong assumption" is the same assumption that is made when flipping a coin. You assume that the coin's fairness does not change with each flip. Also you say that only an "average state" can be reconstructed. If the states are identical, then you can reconstruct the entire probabilty distrubution.

Comment: Also, I added a comment in the answer about using a MZI to see quantum interference of the wavefunction without ever needing to reconstruct collections of identical states, which avoids this "strong assumption" that you are concerned with.

Answer (score 1):

The main point about quantum mechanics historically is that it has assumed that the wave function of a system changes abruptly under certain circumstances which are associated with measurements or observations. The change is considered to be entirely probabilistic- you can work out very precise values for the probability of one type of transition or another, but  there is no what of knowing what is 'really happening' in the background. Indeed there are theorems and experimental results that tell us it's impossible to know what is 'really happening'. So, in principle you can calculate the possible wave functions for a system in a given set of circumstances, and you can calculate the probabilities of the wave function changing abruptly to another wave function as a consequence of a measurement, but you can never get behind the probabilities to something more deterministic.

It's widely accepted that QM has a number of unsustainable conceptual holes in it, notwithstanding the unbelievable accuracy of some of its predictions. The whole business about 'measurements' and observations' is a simplification, since when we say that an electron, for example, has been the subject of a measurement by a measuring device that is assumed to behave classically, what we really mean is that the electron has interacted with other quantum particles in the measuring device in what is probably a very complicated process.

Answer (score 0):

The wavefunction of a quantum system corresponding to an observable is a mathematical object and its square modulus gives the probability density function of the observable of the system. From the probability density function, one can gather information about how likely the system is to have a particular value of the observable.

So, having a full information about the wavefunction doesn't give information about the state in which the quantum system is in. Prior to measurement, the system is said to be in all possible states at the same time or, maybe it is in none of the states. Only after the measurement, its state is defined. One can only determine how likely one is to find the system in a particular state after measurement, if the wavefunction is known.